# Vertical text inside tabu environment

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, tabu

I tried to align the text of the first column vertically. Therefore I used `rotatebox` but I'm not fully satisfied with this solution because the text is aligned on top.

**Question**

What would be a decent solution to align the text of the first column centrally?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,pagesize ,landscape, fontsize=6pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{array,multirow}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{3}

    \tabulinesep=1.0mm
    \begin{tabu} to \columnwidth{> {$\textstyle} X[1,l] < {$} > {$\textstyle} X[30,l] < {$}}
        \multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{polar}}    & \mathbf{r}(\rho, \varphi, z) = \rho\mathbf{e}_\rho(\varphi) + z\mathbf{e}_z \\\cline{2-2}
                                                            & \mathbf{\dot{r}}(\rho, \varphi, z) = \dot{\rho}\mathbf{e}_\rho + \rho\dot{\varphi}\mathbf{e}_\varphi + \dot{z}\mathbf{e}_z \\\cline{2-2}
                                                            & \mathbf{\ddot{r}}(\rho, \varphi, z) = (\ddot{\rho} - \rho\dot{\varphi}^2)\mathbf{e}_\rho + (\rho\ddot{\varphi} + 2\dot{r}\dot{\varphi})\mathbf{e}_\varphi + \ddot{z}\mathbf{e}_z \\\hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{spherical}}& \mathbf{r}(r, \theta, \varphi) = r\mathbf{e}_r(\theta, \varphi) \\\cline{2-2}
                                                            & \mathbf{\dot{r}}(r, \theta, \varphi) = \dot{r}\mathbf{e}_r + r\dot{\theta}\mathbf{e}_\theta + r\sin\theta\dot{\varphi}\mathbf{e}_\varphi \\\cline{2-2}
                                                            & \begin{aligned}
                                                                \mathbf{\ddot{r}}(r, \theta, \varphi)   &= (\ddot{r} - r\dot{\theta}^2\cos^2\varphi - r\dot{\varphi}^2)\mathbf{e}_r  \\
                                                                                                &+ (2\dot{r}\dot{\theta}\cos\varphi + r\ddot{\theta}\cos\varphi - 2r\dot{\theta}\dot{\varphi}\sin\varphi)\mathbf{e}_\theta \\
                                                                                                &+ (2\dot{r}\dot{\varphi} + r\dot{\theta}^2\sin\varphi\cos\varphi + r\ddot{\varphi})\mathbf{e}_\varphi
                                                                 \end{aligned} \\\hline
        \end{tabu}

\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should use more rows for the both `multirow` statements!

Comment: Ow I completely missed that. Thanks Christian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `2` rows for the row-like-combination of cells with `\multirow` is not enough. This is so narrow that the rotated box text is aligned to the top boundary.

I suggest to use `3` rows for the first rotated text and `5` for the second text.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,pagesize ,landscape, fontsize=6pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{array,multirow}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{3}

    \tabulinesep=1.0mm
    \begin{tabu} to \columnwidth{> {$\textstyle} X[1,l] < {$} > {$\textstyle} X[30,l] < {$}}
        \multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{polar}}    & \mathbf{r}(\rho, \varphi, z) = \rho\mathbf{e}_\rho(\varphi) + z\mathbf{e}_z \\\cline{2-2}
                                                            & \mathbf{\dot{r}}(\rho, \varphi, z) = \dot{\rho}\mathbf{e}_\rho + \rho\dot{\varphi}\mathbf{e}_\varphi + \dot{z}\mathbf{e}_z \\\cline{2-2}
                                                            & \mathbf{\ddot{r}}(\rho, \varphi, z) = (\ddot{\rho} - \rho\dot{\varphi}^2)\mathbf{e}_\rho + (\rho\ddot{\varphi} + 2\dot{r}\dot{\varphi})\mathbf{e}_\varphi + \ddot{z}\mathbf{e}_z \\\hline
        \multirow{5}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{spherical}}& \mathbf{r}(r, \theta, \varphi) = r\mathbf{e}_r(\theta, \varphi) \\\cline{2-2}
                                                            & \mathbf{\dot{r}}(r, \theta, \varphi) = \dot{r}\mathbf{e}_r + r\dot{\theta}\mathbf{e}_\theta + r\sin\theta\dot{\varphi}\mathbf{e}_\varphi \\\cline{2-2}
                                                            & \begin{aligned}
                                                                \mathbf{\ddot{r}}(r, \theta, \varphi)   &= (\ddot{r} - r\dot{\theta}^2\cos^2\varphi - r\dot{\varphi}^2)\mathbf{e}_r  \\
                                                                                                &+ (2\dot{r}\dot{\theta}\cos\varphi + r\ddot{\theta}\cos\varphi - 2r\dot{\theta}\dot{\varphi}\sin\varphi)\mathbf{e}_\theta \\
                                                                                                &+ (2\dot{r}\dot{\varphi} + r\dot{\theta}^2\sin\varphi\cos\varphi + r\ddot{\varphi})\mathbf{e}_\varphi
                                                                 \end{aligned} \\\hline
        \end{tabu}

\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

In my opinion, the `\cline{2-2}` should be removed (for optical eye-appeal). I've done this for the screen-shot, but not in the code above:

[image]

Comment: Rethought you idea about erasing the `cline{}` - I think I gonna go with your idea - looks a bit more sleek :) thanks